# Image Upload MVC Components

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm looking for an open source or free ajax component that will allow me to add an image to a form, uploading the image and then display it on the form all using ajax. It need to be able to allow the user to click the image to open a dialog to change the image. I'm not looking for standard browse and upload components

Comment: Maybe look at these suggestions http://jqueryplugin.net/best-jquery-file-upload-plugins-with-image-previews/

Comment: @Chris, thanks this has a good selection. I found one of these 10 ten pages the other day featuring Croppic but this page seems to have some additional options.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this as an option:

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery-ui.html

The source code is available from here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Pretty easy to use:

```
 $(function ()
  {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io' ?
    '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'server/php/';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data)
        {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file)
            {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data)
        {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
            );
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
    .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
```